# Django CreateView: автоматическая установка поля

Tags: python, django

Есть модели `Post` и `Author`:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    post_author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    post_text = models.TextField(null=False)

class Author(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Во `views` он создается через `CreateView`:

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'news/create_post.html'
    form_class = PostForm
```

`Forms` описана в таком виде:

```
class PostForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_author', 'post_text']
```

Можно ли из формы убрать поле `'post_author'` и передать автора не выбирая из списка всех авторов, так как заполняющий форму юзер сам будет являться автором.

Указать в модели `author` как `default=` не получилось, т.к. в модель не смог передать объект `request`.

Answer (score 1):

Можете так попробовать

```
class PostCreateView(CreateView):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.post_author = self.request.user
            instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(......)
        return render(request, 'news/create_post.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

Спасибо за хорошую подсказку! По итогу вышло так:

```
# Джененрик для создания поста
class PostCreateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    template_name = 'news/create_post.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    permission_required = ('news.add_post')
    raise_exception = True

    # Функция для кастомной валидации полей формы модели
    def form_valid(self, form):
        # создаем форму, но не отправляем его в БД, пока просто держим в памяти
        fields = form.save(commit=False)
        # Через реквест передаем недостающую форму, которая обязательна
        fields.post_author = Author.objects.get(author=self.request.user)
        # Наконец сохраняем в БД
        fields.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 0):

models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Post(models.Model)
    post_author = models.ForeIgnKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Автор')
    post_text = models.TexField()
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['post_text']
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import PostForm

class PostCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = PostForm
    template_name = 'create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.post_author = self.request.user
        self.object.save()
        return super(PostCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```